# Python3 installing of Pocketsphinx on linux mint

Tags: python

Good day.I just want to ask anyone of you Face the error of installing of pocketsphinx on python3.Theres a lot of error
I try `pip3 install python-dev` but it doesn't fix it 
This is the error that I Got.

```
albert@linux ~/Downloads $ pip3 install pocketsphinx
n:Collecting pocketsphinx
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
Exceptio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/albert/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/albert/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,....................................

*PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pocketsphinx-0.1.3.dist-info'*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute your script with administrator permissions it will work:

```
sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx
```

At the moment the OS is not giving you the permission to access that location (i.e. dist-packages).

You will need to input your password for it to run as well.

You can learn what [`sudo` does here](https://ilearnstack.com/2013/06/16/what-is-sudo/).

I also prefer to use `python3 -m` at the from to avoid the multiple pips getting mixed up.

For example:

```
sudo python36 -m pip install pocketsphinx
```

As long as you know which interpreter to bring up it will not mix up the different pip commands.